# Flood of low-quality flags!

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, flagging

In the past hour or so there has been a flood of automatic "low quality" flags.

At the moment there are $33$ of them. Almost all are not low quality at all. Seems quite a trouble to start invalidating all (although I would love the challenge of clearing up all my daily flags :-)).

Is there some bug in the software? That never happened before.

Comment: Yes, this is happening on several sites.  We are not alone. I am not clearing them in case a dev needs to look at them.

Comment: Good. I always say, if you are about to drown at least be in good company! :-)

Comment: You might want to post that as an answer so it will be clearly visible to anyone seeing this thread.

Comment: I got nervous that 10k+ users had just stopped caring.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: or when being chased by a bear, be with someone slow.

Comment: @robjohn: Not many bears in Israel, I have to admit. I'll keep that in mind when I'm hiking through Alaska. On the other hand the last leopard should still be alive in the Judea desert. Old, but alive...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There have been currently 36 Community generated "low quality" flags on Math.SE within the last hour.  This is happening on many sites, and the SE staff is looking into it.  I would wait on clearing them as the devs may need to look at them.

**Resolution**

Jarrod Dixon says [on Meta SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155481):

> It's my fault - `!` is a tricky operator.
>
> We'll be pushing a fix out now and cleaning up the flag queues.
>
> My apologies to all moderators.

Things should be better soon.

I've cleared the auto-flags with a score of -1. Hopefully, we won't see more.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155471/community-is-flagging-good-posts-with-low-answer-quality-score-1) is a Meta.SO thread on this.

Comment: This answer just got flagged with a low quality score of 100!

Comment: If you add the confession of Jarrod Dixon from the aforementioned meta thread, I will accept this answer (writing and accepting my own would take two days and I am bound to forget it by then...)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: there!

Comment: Oops; I cleared them before seeing this.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I had already cleared a large number after Jarrod announced that things were fixed. If there were some flags later, perhaps things were not yet fixed.

Comment: We've beat Jarrod appropriately for his malfeasance.